# How do I export an animated png-sequence, imported as images as planes, as glb?

Tags: animation, export

im new to blender and have a problem with exporting an animation.
So I made a gif beforehand but saved it as a png-sequence. I imported the sequence as images as planes into blender. The model I have now in blender consists of a few layers of these 2d- images as planes animations stacked onto each other, and in blender everything looks as it’s supposed to look, and the animations play as they should. When I export it as glb the animation doesn’t play anymore, and I don’t know why.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures